# WCF Operation 'SubmitReview' of contract 'IPanache' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements.

Tags: wcf

I'm stuck with WCF.  I have been accessing the services from javascript no problem but now I have come to access from ASP.NET I have loads of problems. Curretnly I'm getting the error shown in the title.

Not sure if this is an issue but the server is .net and the client is .net 3.5.  Initially it was all working fine without even having to put anything in the web config for the client, don't understand what changed. ASMX pages were so much easier!

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

My servers web.config is...

```
system.serviceModel> 
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
</protocolMapping>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service name="PanacheLib.Services.Panache" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="PanacheLib.Services.IPanache" />
  </service>

</services>


<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  />
```

And my clients web.config is...

```
<system.serviceModel>

<client>
  <endpoint
      name="default"
      address="http://localhost/effect/PanacheSuperbraNew/services/Panache.svc"
      binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="PanacheWcf.IPanache"  behaviorConfiguration="webhttp"/>
</client>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="default"  allowCookies="true" ></binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>




<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors >
    <behavior name="webhttp" >
      <webHttp/>        
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And this is the contract code..

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface IPanache
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    EventCode SubmitReview(string name, int rangeId, string review, int fit, int app, int qal, int val);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    EventCode<List<RangeReview>> GetRangeReviews(int rangeId);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    EventCode<List<Retailer>> GetRetailers(string brands, string address, string country);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    EventCode<List<OnlineRetailer>> GetOnlineRetailers(string brands, string country);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    EventCode<Signup> Singup(string email);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    EventCode<List<RetailerCountry>> GetRetailerCountries();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    EventCode<List<string>> GetUKCounties(eBrand[] brands );

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    EventCode<List<Retailer>> GetRetailersOldSites(eBrand[] brands, decimal latitude, decimal longitude, int? country, bool onWeb, bool onStreat);

}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  I am stuck with exactly the same problem.  Have interface method decorated with BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped but no success.